# Why go to such a disadvantageous time in "Avengers: Endgame"?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

So according to [this](https://www.scoopwhoop.com/entertainment/avengers-endgame-directors-explain--movie-plot-holes/#.jy45po1ko) Q&A by the Russo brothers about *Avengers: Endgame*, Thanos created the tech to travel through time.

So with this tech and the knowledge about the locations of the stones using Nebula's memories, why didn't Thanos just travel through time and space to those locations where he can find the stones very easily instead of going to the very specific time and place where he would be at a certain disadvantage against the Avengers with possibly all the stones.

This is the same Thanos who waited till Odin was out of picture before he made a move for the Tesseract again after using Loki failed to do it for him so we know that Thanos is a patient Titan and from the info he has Thanos should see that the Avengers with Capt. Marvel and the stones are more dangerous than Odin and Thor alone.

And we also know that the "Time GPS" that Tony made can be used to go to some other time and location as well since we see Cap and Tony do it on-screen and are also most probably used by Cap off-screen when he is returning the stones to their places.

And the genius that Thanos is, he surely must have the ability to move through time and space after reverse-engineering the "Time-gps".

Comment: _"This is the same Thanos who waited till Odin was out of picture"_ - There is no canon backing to this theory. It's a popular theory reiterated a lot but as far as I'm aware it is simply a theory and isn't necessarily true.

Answer (score 3):

There's absolutely no reason for Thanos to consider this time as disadvantageous:

- He has reason to think that he can defeat the Avengers, since he's already seen it in Nebula's memory.
- He does not know about the Avengers two heaviest hitters: his future self never met Captain Marvel, and he also does not know about Scarlet Witch (when he finally meets her, he says "[I don't even know who you are.](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154796/characters/nm0647634)").
- He's confident in his own abilities, as well as those of the Black Order and the Outrider army. He also chooses to collect all of the stones at once, rather than find them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

After Avengers return with all the stones from past & using Tony's gauntlet, Banner snaps his fingers & brings everyone back, the Avengers would return the stones in their original timeline as soon as possible to clip all the branches they created. They had no use of the stones apart from bringing everyone back. They had already killed Thanos (in the Garden).

There was a small window available for Thanos to get all the infinity stones that Avengers had collected. So he had to arrive before or immediately after the snap. Before the Avengers returned them to the past

Comment: But why take the risk to face an enemy with a complete gauntlet when Thanos can just teleport through time and space to way easier coordinates where the enemy is much more ignorant about his plans or even his identity, it will only take him 5 seconds in his timeline to go about doing his business,  he can even do the reverse of what cap did at the end and even that would be easier than facing them all together, why so much desperation since from what we have seen Thanos is patient when it comes to  the stones and in this case he has all the time in the world and a cheat-sheet in his hands.

Comment: @usr48 Thanos of the past doesn't know the entire timeline of the stones. He just knows what Nebula knows about the future. Which place would he specifically go to retrieve stones "easily". He goes retrieve stones one by one in Infinity War. This moment was the easiest one since Avengers had all of them. Even if he collected all 5 stones, he would get his ass handed to him by the Ancient One. He would also need to retrieve Aether under Odin's nose. Would that be easier for him?

Comment: Since Nebula was present during the brainstorming sessions, she knows as much as the Avengers do.Tesseract is easy he can go back in time to 1945 or 70 to get it,Mind stone he can get it however he did last time, Power Stone he can get by going back in time and getting it before future Nebula takes it, Soul stone he can get by going back in time with Gamorah to Vormir, he might have to learn to harness the Aether to get the Reality stone and with all five he can surely get the time stone from the Ancient One.

Comment: @usr48 that is the thing. He moved for the stones after Odin, Eggo & the Ancient One died. So how can he retrieve all the stones before Odin & Ancient One dies. We are running in circles with this argument

Comment: @ KharoBangdo He started making a move for the stones way before the events of Ragnarok,GOTG 2 and Doctor Strange. Avengers with all the stones>>>Odin and Ancient One, doesn't seems that hard to see that it would be easier to deal with one heavy hitter at a time instead of a team of mid-tiers(with Thor and Marvel) with the stones.

Comment: @usr48 yes he made moves but not acquire them personally, that would draw attention from other beings in the universe

Comment: @KharoBangdo That theory has been confirmed to be false by the Rousso brothers.

Comment: @DonielF can you link it please

Comment: @KharoBangdo https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/194329/